# How to merge text cells in a table?

Tags: excel, indexing, concatenation, match, lookup

The data below appears in worksheet 1. I need to place the data in worksheet 2 in two columns, the first column being "Month-Year" format, the second column outputs the data below for the corresponding month/year.

e.g.:

```
Year    Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep

1913    9.8 9.8 9.8 9.8 9.7 9.8 9.9 9.9 10.0    

1914   10.0 9.9 9.9 9.8 9.9 9.9 10  10  10
```

The output must read in the following format:

```
MM-YYYY / Data  
Jan-1913 /    9.8  
Feb-1913 / 9.8
```

I need to do this using Excel formulas, not VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Use concatenate?

```
=CONCATENATE(B$1,"-",$A2)
```

And drag the formula across and down.

This assumes that the months are in the first row and the years in the first column, with Jan in B1 and 1913 in A2.

Or use:

```
=B$1&"-"&$A2
```

The dollar sign is locking the rows or columns so that you don't have to re-adjust the formula each time.

EDIT: Seems like you want to fill only one column...

Type `Jan-1913` in cell B2, then type `Feb-1913`. Select both cells and drag down.

[image]

If the date doesn't appear as `mm-yyyy`, just apply a custom formatting.

And fill down, copy and paste as values over the contents of column B.
EDIT: Addendum to additional part in question:

You already have the first column with the above method, so in the second column, use the following formula:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$B$2:$M$102,MATCH(RIGHT(TEXT(Sheet2!A2,"mmm-yyyy"),4)*1,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$102,0),MATCH(LEFT(TEXT(Sheet2!A2,"mmm-yyyy"),3),Sheet1!$B$1:$M$1,0))
```

Replace the ranges and/or worksheet names as appropriate. If this returns `#N/A`, try this one:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$B$2:$M$102,MATCH(RIGHT(TEXT(Sheet2!A2,"mmm-yyyy"),4),Sheet1!$A$2:$A$102,0),MATCH(LEFT(TEXT(Sheet2!A2,"mmm-yyyy"),3),Sheet1!$B$1:$M$1,0))
```

Note that the formulas are using `MATCH()` which means that the cell formats are important and might not work because of this. If for instance the years in Sheet1 are in text format, the second formula will work; not the first, and vice versa.

Comment: When I drag that formula down it gives me the result "Jan-1913" then "Jan-1914".  I need all the months to fill in only ONE column so I won't be dragging anything across.

Comment: I am trying =INDEX(Data!A1:M98,MATCH(LEFT(TEXT(A3,"mmm-yyyy")*Rearranged!A3,3),Data!A1:M1,0),MATCH(RIGHT(TEXT(A3,"mmm-yyyy")*Rearranged!A3,4),Data!A:A,0)) and it's still coming back N/A. do you see anything wrong here?

Comment: @Doug I'm not sure why your ranges are like that... Here's the formula working on google spreadsheet: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Am9GG-rwdOL1dE9TODdLN1pzYW15bDBka2ZfbncwUUE&usp=sharing).

Comment: I see yours working. Excel tells me that formula contains an error and the part ""mmm-" is highlighted.

Comment: @Doug In Sheet2 cell A2, do you have a date or a text? If it's a text, use `=INDEX(Sheet1!$B$2:$M$102,MATCH(RIGHT(A2,4)*1,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$102,0),MATCH(LEFT(A2,3),Sheet1!$B$1:$M$1,0))`

Comment: I have them entered as text.  That formula gives me an error at part LEFT(A2,3) where A2 is highlighted.

Comment: @Doug That's an error caused by the site. Backspace the formula at the opening bracket and the A2 and retype them again (it's because the formula is split into two lines).

Answer (score 0):

I hope you know how to write macros.  (Google visualbasic+excel)

Basically you want to loop over your variables, and concatenate (fancy computer term for combining) your cells.  I believe this should work.

```
Dim monthIdx as Integer
Dim yearIdx as Integer

Dim writeColumnIdx as Integer
Dim myConcatenatedDate as String
writeRowIdx = 2
for yearIdx is 2 to 94
  for monthIdx is 2 to 10
    myConcatenatedDate = Cells(yearIdx, 1).value + "-" + Cells(1, monthIdx).value
    Cells(writeRowIdx, monthIdx).value = myConcatenatedDate
  next monthIdx
next yearIdx
```

Note that the easier solution would be to type Jan-1900 in one cell, move one over and type Feb-1900...  then highlight both the cells, click your cursor over the top-left corner of both boxes and then drag it over adinfinem (maybe). Excel is pretty good at doing those types of things (unless if you only want jan-sep).